# Enable authorization for root path in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, routes, authorization

I have ASP.NET Core application with authorization and it works just fine. But The authorization does not work for the root path of my application.

Here is example (authorization works, because we have [Authorize] attribute above an endpoint:

```
www.example.com/cars
```

Here is what I need to authorize also but it doesn't work:

```
www.example.com
```

Comment: You can try to add `[Authorize]` to the default action of `www.example.com`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made this possible by the `[Route]` attribute above a default action.